# $2 \mid \lvert x-y \rvert$ is the relation reflexive symmetric anti-symmetric and transitive in the set $A= \Bbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> 1.Given the relation $2 \mid \lvert x-y \rvert$ where $2$ is the divisor of $\lvert x-y\rvert$ check if the relation is reflexive symmetric anti-symmetric and transitive in the set $A= \Bbb Z$
>
> 2. same thing for $\lvert C -D \rvert \geq 2$ (the size of the difference of 2 sets) in the set $A=P(\Bbb Z)$

for the first one:

$xRy \iff 2 \mid \lvert x-y \rvert $

reflexive because for every $a \in A=P(\Bbb Z)$ we have $(a,a)\in A=P(\Bbb Z)$ because $2\mid \lvert a-a\rvert=0 \in A=P(\Bbb Z)$

symmetric because of the property of absolute value $\lvert x-y\rvert=\lvert y-x\rvert$ so $2\mid \lvert x-y\rvert = 2\mid \lvert y-x\rvert$

not anti-symmetric because $2R4$ and $4R2$ fulfill the following $\frac{\lvert 4-2 \rvert}{2}=2$ and $\frac{\lvert2-4\rvert}{2}=2$ but $2 \neq 4.$

for transitive I don't know if it is correct but let $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$ so we get $\lvert x-y\rvert=2k$ and $\lvert y-z\rvert=2m$ $(k,m \in \Bbb N)$ so we have 2 equation if we sum them we get

$\lvert y-z\rvert+\lvert x-y\rvert=2(m+k)$ if we remove the absolute value we get $x-z=2(m+k)$ which means it is transitive but I am not sure if this is correct.

for the second question:

not reflexive because for all $a \in A$ we have $\lvert a-a\rvert=0 \not \geq 2$

not symmetric because if $D= \{1\}$ and $C=\{1,2,3\}$ then $\lvert C-D\rvert=2$ but $\lvert D-C\rvert=0 \not \geq 2$ therefore it is not symmetric

also not anti-symmetric because let $D=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{3,4\}$ then $\lvert C-D\rvert=2=\lvert D-C\rvert$ but $C \not = D$

I don't know how to check transitive, I understand the definition but I don't know how to actually do it$\dots$

Thanks for any tips and tricks, I hope the translations are understandable.

Comment: For the first example, it helps to recognize that this can be rephrased as "*two numbers are related iff they are the same* **parity**", that is to say evens are related to evens, odds are related to odds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Transitivity is true but the proof is not good. Note $\lvert x-y\rvert+\lvert y-z\rvert=\lvert x-z\rvert$ is not always valid. However, you could get rid of the absolute value to start with. $2\mid \lvert x-y\rvert$ is equivalent to $2\mid (x-y)$ anyways, so you could've used the latter condition, and all you will need there is $x-z=(x-y)+(y-z)$.
2. Say $X=\{1,2\}$, $Y=\{3,4\}$, $Z=X$. (The same counterexample as for anti-symmetry.)

Comment: Thank you , but why did you get rid of the absolute value from the beginning?

Comment: Why not? The conditions are equivalent to each other, therefore they describe *the same relation*, and if the second condition is easier to work with - all the better! And they are indeed equivalent, because $x$ is even if and only if $|x|$ is even.